# SELECT non-duplicate records joined to table with duplicate date records, by last date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

The title probably doesn't make much sense, so I'll try to be descriptive here in the subject.

Consider 2 tables in MSSQL2005:

Cases table:

```
id int,
caseNo string
```

Events table:

```
id int,
caseID int,
eventDate date/time
```

I need a select statement for a view which will return **single** rows of:
cases.caseNo, events.eventDate (date part only)

They are related/joined by `events.caseID = cases.id` many to one. There are multiple event records per case records.  I want the resultset to be single `caseNo` with the latest/most recent value of events.eventDate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `max` function to grab the latest date, like so:

```
select
    c.caseNo,
    max(e.eventDate) as eventDate
from
    cases c
    inner join events e on
        c.id = e.caseid
group by
    c.caseNo
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 5 ways to do this, these are described here: [Including an Aggregated Column's Related Values](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/including-an-aggregated-column-s-related)

Basically something like this if you need more than just the date and the case id

```
select e.*,c.*
from(
select caseID,max(evendate) as MaxEventDate
from Events
group by caseID) x
join Cases c on c.Id = x.caseID
join Events e on e.eventDate =  x.MaxEventDate
and e.caseID = x.caseID
```

otherwise just group by id and use max for date

```
select  max(e.EventDate) as MaxEventDate,
    c.CaseNo
from
    Cases c
    join Events e on
        e.caseid = c.id 
group by c.caseNo
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, SQLMenace.  The link to the article will be useful.